# Transparent beam

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to combine a quick model with a background in compositor and I want my sunlight beam (yellow) to be mixed with the blue sky, how do I do that? I tried working with Alpha over, but i wasn't succesful. Thanks for the answer.

[image: ufo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The problem is, that the mask is mixing the images in a binary way (either one or the other).

To make them blend together more smoothly you should use a math node (with multiplication) between the "beam" node and the "Mix" node.

Set the factor to something like .5 and start adjusting from there. (you might need to invert the node and switch the inputs depending on the output of the "beam" node)

With the sunbeam having a gradient from yellow to black you could also plug this in as multiplication factor to get the alpha adjusted by the brightness. The brighter parts will be more opaque than the darker parts. Be sure to run this through something like a color ramp to get good control.

You might also try to "Add" instead of "Mix" as the blend option on the "mix" node as a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to either change mix to add or use mix with multiply. It only differed in the beam intensity. I also had to add a new mask to define the area for the yellow beam, since i didn't want the blue beam emitting from that blue color. The only problem is that the beam has aliasing. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I think at this point you need to ask a new question and upload a blendfile. The image in the initial question had all relevant information (IMHO a good question), but for the follow up it would be important to have a blendfile with the images packed inside. (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)